# Set input text default value and select option value then disable

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, how can I:

- set a default value (and disable it) on the textbox
- disable the `<select>` option "Days"

? This is my HTML:

```html
Deliver every <input type="text" maxlength="2" size="3"> 
<select>
<option value="Days">Days</option>
<option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
</select>
```

Comment: See the `disabled` and `selected` attributes. That part doesn’t even need JavaScript. As for disabling a default value in the textbox… can you give an example of what you mean, please?

Comment: <input type='text' value='test' readonly='true'>

Comment: @minitech yes, I know I can use disabled and selected, but my manager require me to use JavaScript. I am not just sure if JavaScript can do that and I dont know how also. Thanks

Comment: That doesn’t make sense as a requirement. Perhaps you could ask your manager to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one would work.

```
<input type="text" id="defaultDays" size="3">
<select id="disableOption">
<option value="Days">Days</option>
<option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.getElementById('defaultDays').setAttribute('value','28');
  document.getElementById('defaultDays').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('disableOption').disabled = true;
</script>
```

Thank you guys for your previous comments.